# How to Convert a sentence to Interrogative in requesting way?

Tags: sentence-construction, interrogatives

Actually I have a scenario to rename the Query to slick (requesting
manner) way.

Statement:

> "Model not binding properly in nodejs"

Converted to Interrogative:

> "Why Model is not binding Properly in nodejs?"

It does not seem to be requesting . Is it good way to convert like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When transforming a sentence to an interrogative, you write it as : Why is...

So...

> Why is the model not binding properly in nodejs?

You essentially switch the position of "is."

Comment: this is a good site to Get Better English !!